# Unable to start Geoserver after reboot

Tags: geoserver, geonode

I have Geoserver 2.7 (installed via GeoNode 2.4 package) in Ubuntu server 14.04. I´ve been using it in GeoNode for a couple of months with no problem. After rebooting the server, it´s not starting any more. Geonode works fine, but can´t access layers through local geoserver. I´m new in this so i allredy ran out of ideas on how to solve it.

I tried to start it via Tomcat7 manager (localhost:8080/manager) but get this:

```
FALLO - No se pudo arrancar la aplicación en trayectoria de contexto /geoserver

catalina log file show some errors (I post only last part, it´s too long)
INFORMACIÃ“N: Unregistering JAI factory class 

com.sun.media.jai.tilecodec.GZIPTileEncoderFactory
ene 18, 2017 3:08:41 PM org.geoserver.GeoserverInitStartupListener 

contextDestroyed
INFORMACIÃ“N: Cleaned up javabean caches
ene 18, 2017 3:08:42 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader 

clearReferencesJdbc
GRAVE: La aplicaciÃ³n web [/geoserver] registrÃ³ el conductor JDBC 

[org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver] pero fallÃ³ al anular el registro mientras la 

aplicaciÃ³n web estaba parada. Para prevenir un fallo de memoria, se ha anulado 

el registro del conductor JDBC por la fuerza.
ene 18, 2017 3:08:42 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader 

clearReferencesThreads
GRAVE: La aplicaciÃ³n web [/geoserver] parece haber arrancado un hilo llamado 

[pool-6-thread-1] pero no ha podido pararlo. Esto tiene todas las papeletas de 

convertirse en un fallo de memoria.
ene 18, 2017 3:08:42 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader 

clearReferencesThreads
GRAVE: La aplicaciÃ³n web [/geoserver] parece haber arrancado un hilo llamado 

[pool-6-thread-2] pero no ha podido pararlo. Esto tiene todas las papeletas de 

convertirse en un fallo de memoria.
ene 18, 2017 3:08:42 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader 

clearReferencesThreads
GRAVE: La aplicaciÃ³n web [/geoserver] parece haber arrancado un hilo llamado 

[pool-6-thread-4] pero no ha podido pararlo. Esto tiene todas las papeletas de 

convertirse en un fallo de memoria.
ene 18, 2017 3:08:42 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader 

clearReferencesThreads
GRAVE: La aplicaciÃ³n web [/geoserver] parece haber arrancado un hilo llamado 

[pool-6-thread-3] pero no ha podido pararlo. Esto tiene todas las papeletas de 

convertirse en un fallo de memoria.
ene 18, 2017 3:08:42 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader 

clearReferencesThreads
GRAVE: La aplicaciÃ³n web [/geoserver] parece haber arrancado un hilo llamado 

[H2 File Lock Watchdog /usr/share/geoserver/data/monitoring/monitoring.lock.db] 

pero no ha podido pararlo. Esto tiene todas las papeletas de convertirse en un 

fallo de memoria.
```

I was looking for a startup.sh file in a /geoserver folder but there is no such folder. I found a usr/share/tomcat7/bin/startup.sh , wich throws this message when i run it:

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/share/tomcat7
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/share/tomcat7
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/share/tomcat7/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr
Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/share/tomcat7/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
touch: no se puede efectuar `touch' sobre «/usr/share/tomcat7/logs/catalina.out»: No existe el archivo o el directorio
./catalina.sh: 385: ./catalina.sh: cannot create /usr/share/tomcat7/logs/catalina.out: Directory nonexistent
```

If there´s files and folders missing, I wonder how it was working fine before the reboot. must be another problem i guess.. or some path changed but i don´t know where to see that.
Any ideas?

EDIT: I add the first lines of the catalina log

```
    ene 18, 2017 3:08:24 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader 

validateJarFile
INFORMACIÃ“N: validateJarFile(/usr/share/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/servlet-api-

2.5.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending 

class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
ene 18, 2017 3:08:36 PM org.geoserver.platform.GeoServerExtensions checkContext
ADVERTENCIA: Extension lookup 'XStreamPersisterInitializer', but 

ApplicationContext is unset.
ene 18, 2017 3:08:39 PM org.geoserver.platform.GeoServerExtensions checkContext
ADVERTENCIA: Extension lookup 'GeoServerSecurityProvider', but 

ApplicationContext is unset.
ene 18, 2017 3:08:39 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
GRAVE: Error listenerStart
ene 18, 2017 3:08:39 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
GRAVE: FallÃ³ en arranque del Contexto [/geoserver] debido a errores previos
ene 18, 2017 3:08:40 PM org.geoserver.GeoserverInitStartupListener 

contextDestroyed
INFORMACIÃ“N: Beginning GeoServer cleanup sequence
ene 18, 2017 3:08:40 PM org.geoserver.GeoserverInitStartupListener 

contextDestroyed
INFORMACIÃ“N: Unregistered JDBC driver org.h2.Driver@8f2575
ene 18, 2017 3:08:40 PM org.geoserver.GeoserverInitStartupListener 

disposeAuthorityFactories
INFORMACIÃ“N: Disposing referencing factory GeoserverWKTOperationFactory
```

Comment: All of the errors you have included are related to geoserver trying to shutdown after the problem (basically it's crashed and lots is failing) - you need to go upwards and find the first ERROR and put that in the question.

Comment: It starts with some warnings about ApplicationContext unset, followed by Error listenerStart. So do i have to set the context in some file? --I added first lines in the question-